# onPause in eclipse gives syntax error and void is invalid type

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using the onPause method in my activity, but I'm receiving the following errors:

```
Syntax error, insert ";"to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement

void is an invalid type for the variable onPause
```

Code:

```
public class MusicActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_music);

    final MediaPlayer MP = MediaPlayer.create(MusicActivity.this, R.raw.burntumber);

    Button burntumberPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start1Button);
    burntumberPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MP.start();
        }
    });

    Button burntumberStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop1Button);
    burntumberStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MP.pause();
                            MP.seekTo(0);
        }
    });

    @Override
    protected void onPause{
        super.onPause();
        MP.stop();
        MP.release();
    };

}
}
```

EDIT:

```
public class MusicActivity extends Activity {

MediaPlayer MP = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_music);


    MP = MediaPlayer.create(MusicActivity.this, R.raw.burntumber);

    Button burntumberPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start1Button);
    burntumberPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MP.start();
        }
    });

    Button burntumberStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop1Button);
    burntumberStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //MP.stop(); //won't restart when start() is run again
            MP.pause();
            //MP.seekTo(0);
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onPause{
    super.onPause();
    MP.stop();
    MP.release();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.music, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Errors:

```
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration
The annotation @Override is disallowed for this location
void is an invalid type for the variable onPause
```

Comment: You are missing a `}` to close the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Edited the post with mediaplayer declared outside of onCreate method

Comment: @KFP Found the other problem. See my edit

Answer (score 2):

Your method is inside `onCreate()` and has a ";" at the end of it. It is a separate method so should not be inside a method.

```
public class MusicActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_music);

    // onCreate() code

}

@Override
protected void onPause{
    super.onPause();
    MP.stop();
    MP.release();
}
```

**Edit**

You are also missing the "()" for the `onPause()` method. That is why Eclipse thinks it is a Field instead of a method. Change it to

```
   @Override
   protected void onPause(){  // missing the parenthesis here
        super.onPause();
        MP.stop();
        MP.release();
   }
```

Comment: I did originally try that way, but I get 'The annotation @Override is disallowed for this location' and void is an invalid type for the variable onPause.

Comment: Then edit with that code because that's what you need. Make sure it is inside your class but outside of any activity

Comment: @KFP you shouldn't edit your OP and take out the original code but rather add the new code. Do you have a closing bracket for your `Activity` after the `onPause()` method?

Comment: Sorry about that...I'll change it back with the new edits at bottom.

Comment: No problem. Thanks. Otherwise it is useless to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Remove SemiColon at the end of onPause Method

```
protected void onPause{
super.onPause();
MP.stop();
MP.release();
 }
```

Comment: That's not the only issue.

Comment: after it your are missing } for activity